# mod_rewrite remove www for all domains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, multiple-domains, no-www

I have multiple domains all pointing to the same website and depending on which domain you enter the website, will determine which categories will be selected.

For this to work I have to place any Mod_Rewrite code inside my
    apache2/sites-available/primarydomain
file.

The website has the potential to host hundreds of domains so I need a system where I dont have to write a rule out for each domain eventuality.

I have seen this suggested online

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it doesnt work for me.

Does any regex guru out there know if this is even achievable?

Heres hoping :-)

Comment: This rule looks fine to me - when you say it doesn't work, what does it do? Are you sure the file is being read?

Comment: I dont know why but all of a sudden it is now working.  What was happening was I was getting a load of % signs and the domain name repeating and repeating.  Just one slight issue with the code though is that www.domain.com is now becoming domain.com// with two trailing slashes so I removed the / from between the %1/$1 and it is working fine now.  Many thanks